Data display the same to every collection created
I created in flutter a fitness app and I am on my profile screen. I want the user to  show another data when a new category is created, I will show the issue here : https://imgur.com/a/XiStzun
Here it's the code for the page where workout schedule appears and all widgets( most essentially because all code doesn't fit)
    class WorkoutContentAdded extends StatefulWidget {
      final String programId;
    
      const WorkoutContentAdded({Key? key, required this.programId}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _WorkoutContentAddedState createState() => _WorkoutContentAddedState();
    }
    
    class _WorkoutContentAddedState extends State<WorkoutContentAdded> {
      late Stream<QuerySnapshot> _workoutScheduleStream;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _initializeWorkoutScheduleStream();
      }
    
      @override
      void didUpdateWidget(WorkoutContentAdded oldWidget) {
        super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
        if (oldWidget.programId != widget.programId) {
          _initializeWorkoutScheduleStream();
        }
      }
 void _initializeWorkoutScheduleStream() {
    print('Initializing workout schedule stream for program: ${widget.programId}');
    _workoutScheduleStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('programs')
        .doc(widget.programId)
        .collection('workout_schedule')
        .orderBy('order')
        .snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Building WorkoutContentAdded for program: ${widget.programId}');
    return Scaffold(
      // ... other scaffold properties
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          // ... other slivers
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Workout Schedule',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: _workoutScheduleStream,
                    builder: (context, scheduleSnapshot) {
 print('Workout schedule stream update for program: ${widget.programId}');
                      print('Connection state: ${scheduleSnapshot.connectionState}');
                      if (scheduleSnapshot.hasError) {
                        print('Error in schedule stream: ${scheduleSnapshot.error}');
                      }
                      if (scheduleSnapshot.hasData) {
                        print('Number of workout days: ${scheduleSnapshot.data!.docs.length}');
                      }

                      if (scheduleSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }

                      if (scheduleSnapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('Error: ${scheduleSnapshot.error}');
                      }

                      if (!scheduleSnapshot.hasData || scheduleSnapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                          child: Text('No workout schedule added for this program.'),
                        );
                      }

                      List<DocumentSnapshot> sortedDocs = scheduleSnapshot.data!.docs;

                      return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: sortedDocs.length,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
 Map<String, dynamic> data = sortedDocs[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                          String day = data['day'] ?? 'Unknown Day';
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => VideoContent(
                                    day: day,
                                    allowEditing: true,
                                    programId: widget.programId,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            child: Card(
                              // Card content
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
                ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _showAddCategoryBottomSheet,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.startFloat,
    );
  }
void _showAddCategoryBottomSheet() {
    String selectedOrdinal = '1st';
    String selectedDay = 'Monday';
    String estimatedKcal = '';

    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
                left: 24,
                right: 24,
                top: 24,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Choose the day of the week',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                          value: selectedOrdinal,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                          ),
                          items: ['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th']
                              .map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            if (newValue != null) {
                              setState(() {
                                selectedOrdinal = newValue;
                              });
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                          value: selectedDay,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                          ),
                          items: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
                              .map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            if (newValue != null) {
                              setState(() {
                                selectedDay = newValue;
                              });
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Estimative kcal burnt',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      estimatedKcal = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Center(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('workout_schedule').add({
                          'ordinal': selectedOrdinal,
                          'day': selectedDay,
                          'estimatedKcal': estimatedKcal,
                        });
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: Text('Save'),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 16),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        );
      },
    );
  }

    
    


You shared a lot of code and a use-case. What specific part of the code you shared doesn't work the way you expect it to work? I recommend reading How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example, as following the guidance in there makes it much more likely that someone can help.

It looks like you are listening to something wrong. Try to minimize your code and test step by step
